# Does adding ngrx always prove itself (in angular project)

Tags: angular, ngrx

We are about to refactor an old project into angular which mainly displays data  without allowing user updates (no 2 way data-bindings).
Updates will only be done via dedicated wizards (by calling an api at the end).

I have worked in angular projects with/out ngrx. I feel that using ngrx to this type of project will add unneeded complexity and will slow the development a lot, while using few simple services may speed up our development greatly.

Despite that, it seems that most of the projects automatically using ngrx.

We would appreciate some thoughts on the matter to help decide or alternatives you have used.

Comment: I am not ngrx expert but I was told only projects complex enough that state management is a problem then you use the Redux pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I using it in every project. Once you've implemented the first store, you will see how easy it. The advantages are also in performance, a stable workflow for the whole team and many more. You can check https://github.com/co-IT/co-it/tree/master/ngrx/ducks to simplify store implementation.

this could also help you: https://medium.com/@thomasburleson_11450/ngrx-facades-better-state-management-82a04b9a1e39

and this presentation: https://speakerdeck.com/gregonnet/ngrx-refactoring-patterns

UPDATE:
another interesting link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmnsEvoy-gY